# yii2 pretty url with anchors

Tags: yii2, bookmarks, pretty-urls

How to enable pretty urls in yii2, and permit the use of anchors?
I have a website, where in the main page I need to use anchors.
Without enabling pretty url every thing was running perfect with the use of `Url::to(['site/index', '#' => 'work'])` in the header of the page. But when I configured pretty url, I get the following:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /shekh/index.php was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking for is not a bookmark but an anchor.

I'm assuming here `/shekh` is the folder pointing to the application's folder with `index.php` so it's your base URL.
When you switch pretty URLs on with configuration like `'showScriptName' => false` previous address `/shekh/index.php` is not valid anymore.
Now just `/shekh` shoud point to `index` action of `site` controller (with default settings). The same you get when using `/shekh/site` or `/shekh/site/index`.

I'm guessing you have set everything without pretty URLs, entered `/shekh/index.php`, then switched pretty URLs on and refreshed the page. If so - just delete the `index.php` part.

Comment: thank you.I found that I have added .htaccess file to the base dir of my app instead of putting it in the web folder. Sory for my fault !!